# Npm nx got failed，but not much error ， How do I find what's really wrong?

Tags: node.js, angular, nomachine-nx, taiga

I got a open source project from github.https://github.com/taigaio/taiga.git I just try to build the front part of the project like the dockerfile in the project, which under the path docker/image/dockerfile.front.npm.  npm install && npm run build:prod. I got failed. so I add the --verbose.I got this.
[root@iZbp1569ap9cnc4gjc56zfZ javascript]# nx build --verbose taiga --prod

> nx run taiga:build:production

⠹ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...    [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] No pack exists at /root/taiga/javascript/.angular/cache/16.2.1/angular-webpack/dcb626848f205c0142e89763ec63a50971843d40.pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/root/taiga/javascript/.angular/cache/16.2.1/angular-webpack/dcb626848f205c0142e89763ec63a50971843d40/index.pack'
 [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] restore cache container: 26084.548976 ms
⠴ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

> NX   Running target build for project taiga failed

Failed tasks:

- taiga:build:production

Hint: run the command with --verbose for more details.
Is the final failure caused by missing this file?

I want the project to be able to build a dist folder.
Regarding this question, I just want to get some suggestions for troubleshooting errors. I don’t know much about nodejs.

Comment: The error states that a file (/root/taiga/javascript/.angular/cache/16.2.1/angular-webpack/dcb626848f205c0142e89763ec63a50971843d40/index.pack) is missing.
I cannot reproduce locally. 
Which versions of `npm` and `node` are you using?